# Activities: combine completed date (tasks) and activity date (events) into a single field

Tags: reporting, tasks, activities

How to create reports with a filter on completed date-time of tasks and events? They are both stored as "activities", but the completion information is stored differently:

- Task completion date-time is stored in `CompletedDateTime`, whereas `ActivityDate` is different and shows when the task was due.
- Events do not have `CompletedDateTime`, so we have to assume that `ActivityDateTime` is when the activity took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom field formula that I ended up using

```
IF(
IsTask = TRUE,
CompletedDateTime,
IF(ActivityDateTime < NOW(),
ActivityDateTime,
NULL)
)
```

- To create, go to Setup -> Object Manager -> Activity
- If the event is in the future, this will return NULL (convenient for filtering)